# Using Gibbs entropy to sum entropy of subsystems. Why does this not equal the Gibbs entropy of the total system?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I have found the Gibbs entropy of a simple system and the summed Gibbs entropy of its subsystems. I believed that these values should be equal. They are not. I'd be grateful for any ideas regarding where I have went wrong.

Consider an isolated system, $S$, which can be split into two subsystems: $L$ and $R$.

There are ten microstates of system $S$. Subsystem $L$ can be in one of three microstates, $A_1^L$, $B^L_1$ and $B^L_2$. Subsystem $R$ can be in one of seven microstates, $A_1^R$, $A_2^R$, $A_3^R$, $A_4^R$, $B^R_1$, $B^R_2$ and $B^R_3$.

If subystem $L$ is in a microstate of type $A$ then so is $R$ (same for $B$ microstates). This is due to conservation of energy. Let $E(A^L)$ be the energy of the subsystem $L$ in an $A$ state. Likewise for other terms of this form. Let $E(A^L)+E(A^R)=E(B^L)+E(B^R)=U$, where $U$ is the total energy of $S$. Let $E(A^L) \neq E(B^L)$.

The ten possible microstates of the overall system $S$ are thus:

$A_1^L$ $A_1^R$,

$A_1^L$ $A_2^R$,

$A_1^L$ $A_3^R$,

$A_1^L$ $A_4^R$,

$B_1^L$ $B_1^R$,

$B_1^L$ $B_2^R$,

$B_1^L$ $B_3^R$,

$B_2^L$ $B_1^R$,

$B_2^L$ $B_2^R$,

$B_2^L$ $B_3^R$

Each microstate of $S$ is equally likely. Thus the probability $S$ is in any one of these ten microstates is $\frac{1}{10}$.

The Gibbs total entropy of system $S$, given by $-\sum_i P_i \log P_i$, is simply $\log 10$. (Let $k_B=1$)

Let us find the Gibbs entropy of subsystem $L$. The probability it is in state $A_1^L$ is $\frac{4}{10}$. This is because there are four overall system microstates where $L$ is in this state. Likewise $L$ is in state $B_1^L$ with probability $\frac{3}{10}$, equivalently for state $B_2^L$. Thus the entropy of subsystem $L$ is

$-[\frac{4}{10}\log\frac{4}{10}+\frac{3}{10}\log\frac{3}{10}+\frac{3}{10}\log\frac{3}{10}]=-[\frac{4}{10}\log\frac{4}{10}+\frac{6}{10}\log\frac{3}{10}]$

Likewise the entropy of subsystem $R$ is

$-[\frac{1}{10}\log\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\log\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\log\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\log\frac{1}{10} + \frac{2}{10}\log\frac{2}{10}+\frac{2}{10}\log\frac{2}{10}+\frac{2}{10}\log\frac{2}{10}]$

$=-[\frac{4}{10}\log\frac{1}{10}+\frac{6}{10}\log\frac{2}{10}]$

The sum of subsystem $R$ and subsystem $L$ entropies is,

$2\log10 -\frac{4}{10}\log4 -\frac{6}{10}\log 6$

$=2\log10 -\frac{1}{10}\log 256-\frac{1}{10}\log 46656$

$=2\log10 -\log5.1$

$\neq \log 10$

So, the total entropy is not equal to the summed entropy of the system's subsystems. What has went wrong? Why can Gibbs entropy not be manipulated in this way?

Comment: If $L$ has 1 $A$-type and 2 $B$-types, $R$ has 4 $A$-types and 1 $B$-type, you have 6 states, not 10. So $R$ had 3 $B$-type states. Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. R has 3 B-type states. Typo now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: the entropy of two subsystems only decomposes into a sum when the systems are approximately independent (in a statistical sense). If they are strongly coupled, as the ones in the example are, you need to turn to [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy) to manage the sum.

Long story short, the correct equation is:
\begin{align}
 H(X,Y) & = H(X|Y) + H(Y)
\end{align}
because the definition of how joint probability $P(X,Y)$ and conditional probability $P(X|Y)$ is
\begin{align}
 P(X,Y) & = P(X|Y) P(Y).
\end{align}
When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X|Y) = P(X)$.

For completeness, conditional entropy is defined as
\begin{align}
  H(X|Y) & = - \sum_{X,Y} P(X,Y) \ln P(X|Y)
\end{align}
and, if $P(X|Y) = P(X)$ then you can show that $H(X|Y) = H(X)$.

I leave applying this to the particular example in the question as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It may be worth adding that "when the subsystems are (strongly) coupled" the total(joint) entropy is always *less* than the sum of the subsystems. We see it in OP example